# after pseudo element does not work correctly in hr tag on Internet Explorer

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer

The below code works well on all browsers except Internet Explorer.
In IE the wording seems to be compressed to `1px` `height` or covered by the `hr` gradient.
What's causing this problem?

```css
.hr-how {
  text-align: center;
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
}
.hr-how:after {
  content: "HOW TO USE IT";
  display: inline-block;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.7em;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0 0.6em;
  background: white;
}
```

```html
<hr class="hr-how" id="hr-how">
```

http://jsfiddle.net/y8nx51rf/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is happening because the default setting for `overflow` on `hr` tags is `visible` in Chrome and Firefox but `hidden` in IE. This causes any content outside the `height` of the `hr` to be cut off in IE.

To make this work in IE add `overflow: visible;` to `.hr-how` so the text can extend outside the boundaries of the `hr`.

```css
.hr-how {
  background-image: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75), rgba(0, 0, 0, 0));
  border: 0;
  height: 1px;
  margin-bottom: 40px;
  margin-top: 40px;
  overflow: visible;
  text-align: center;
}
.hr-how:after {
  background: white;
  content: "HOW TO USE IT";
  display: inline-block;
  font: "BodoniXT" !important;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  padding: 0 0.6em;
  position: relative;
  top: -0.7em;
}
```

```html
<hr class="hr-how" id="hr-how" />
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer! Modern Chrome also seems to be defaulting to overflow: hidden on hr elements. I had to set that globally so my :before pseudo/background image would show.